# What cryptographically secure options are there for creating random numbers in WinRT?

Tags: random, windows-8, cryptography, windows-runtime

Ordinarily I'd do something like this:

```
byte[] randomBytes = new byte[bytes];
string randomString = Convert.ToBase64String(new RNGCryptoServiceProvider().GetBytes(randomBytes));
```

However there's no RNGCryptoServiceProvider available.

Are there any secure random alternatives available?

Thanks,

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I managed to find an equivalent.

```
using Windows.Security.Cryptography;

IBuffer randomBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.GenerateRandom(PASSWORD_SALT_LENGTH);
string randomString = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(randomBuffer)
```

I hope this is of use to someone else.

Comment: I honestly can't remember, I was in an incompatibility fugue nightmare at the time :)